# How basic types get stored in asp.net session variable

Tags: .net, session-variables

I need to know How basic types Int, enum, string get stored in session variable. Are they get serialized first before storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends entirely on how session state is configured.

If you just store session state in-memory, serialization is not needed. The variables are stored straight into a dictionary object.

If you store session state on a session state server or in the database, then the variables are indeed serialized and deserialized all the time.

You can find out more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx.